# WiFi Connection Keeps Cutting Out

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (64bit) and the internet connection keeps cutting out non-stop! I have updated the kernel to the most recent one and tried all other methods (after doing research) and it still keeps cutting out. I can't stop the damn thing from roaming either! Nothing works!

When will this issue get fixed? I'm at my wits end! I thought Linux was supposed to be great but it has cost me a lot of my time and even possibly a job so far! I'm doing a web development course online also that keeps cutting out! I was on a video interview which cut out and that's it! end of story now for that job!

I have come from Windows to Linux so I am a newbie. I am career changing now to Programming and Web Development. I am learning. But from all the research I have done, I have now come to an end and in desperate need of help. Surely this wifi connection problem cannot really be such a serious issue in such a great operating system such as Linux??? Can someone please help me?

It's not my internet connection either. It works perfectly without any problems on my other computer.

Disabling IPv6 has not helped either.

And please don't be nasty in your comments. I have a bad anxiety problem to put it mildly :(
We were all beginners at one stage. I am trying to learn and fix this issue on my own but nothing helped. I see this is an ongoing issue with Linux. I'm so tired of this problem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1551115

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.